# Failed to resolve: support-compat ONLY FOR :27.1.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, gradle-dependencies, dependency-resolution

I have an android module with this `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 27

        defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 14
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0.0"
        }
}

dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
}
```

And received this error during Gradle sync process:

> Failed to resolve: support-compat

The dependency identifier that I used is exactly according to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v4-compat (when I write this question).

*The interesting note is the problem is **only for version `27.1.1`**!* All other versions that I tested (`24.2.0`, `26.0.0`, `27.0.0` and even `27.1.0`) are OK.

Also, *All other support libraries that I tested from this version (`27.1.1`) are OK*. Here a list of them:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' 
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' 
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

---

Screanshot:

[image]

There is no difference if I insert the dependency in `app` module or `library` module.

---

My project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

---

My `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
#Wed Jul 18 14:24:51 IRDT 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check whether you included this in the repositories section of app gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what happened! replacing both `google()` with `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` solved the problem. Now replacing it to back makes no issue!!! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

The `google()` repository needs to be listed before the `jcenter()` repository. I can reproduce the issue by swapping their order under `allprojects`.

Answer (score 2):

Try as follow:

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //use maven repo
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }

        jcenter()
    }
}
```